# Testing C memory leaks with Xcode

Tags: c, memory-leaks, malloc

I'm kinda new to C and Xcode. I'm running my application and in the debug navigator panel, my memory time, keeps increasing but no leaks were found by instruments. Is it a leak? The picture which I've added is just keeps increasing. But the size remains constant, 5.1MB

[Memory leak](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUPGs.png)

Comment: No, that isn't indicative of a memory leak.

Comment: Thanks! I have checked it with Instruments, at everything was fine there.